# Navigate faster on space indented java source files in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a project where indentation in java source code is with spaces (four spaces when you press Tab).
I want to move left and right with the arrow keys skipping 4 spaces at a time, not a single space.
I know I can do that if I migrate space indentation to tab indentation, but I cannot do that.

The IDEA is version 12.x

Btw, here's the option that allows to right-arrow end of line and go to the beginning of the next line and if you down-arrow a line to go to the end of next line, not on the same column far after the end of line:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + arrow is your friend, it allows moving to the previous/next word, and skips spaces. You can also use the "beginning of line" key (the <kbd>Home</kbd> key), which allows you to switch between the first character and the first non-indentation character.

Comment: Yeah, I am using Ctrl+arrows, that's a good one, but I want more :)